# Meaning of AE3803’s Name

Tags: cells-at-work

In the anime *Cells at Work* (*Hataraku Saibou*) that is currently airing, AE3803 is a Red Blood Cell who does not have a sense of direction while delivering packages to different parts of the human body. What does “AE” stand for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no official statement for the production, but it seems the AE3803 is [hexcode for a shade of red](http://www.color-hex.com/color/ae3803).

Answer (score 1):

Well, the hex color it leads to is technically called 'Rust'... So maybe you could say that the author indirectly or, perhaps deliberately, named her 'Rusty'. It would explain why she is so clumsy but, then again, I do not know much about Japanese culture or anything. So saying that someone is being rusty might not make sense in translation. It's a thought, though. I'm curious though. What are the Japanese words for 'rust' or 'rusty'? Maybe it makes for a fun nickname.